# What happens when an object is destroyed while a glibmm thread created from it is still running?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gtkmm, glibmm

Consider the following scenario: There is a class `A`, which upon construction (lets call object as `objA`) runs a member function `run()` as a glibmm thread. `objA.run()` is doing some intensive processing & may even be blocked on some system call waiting for IO. Now the object `objA` is destroyed in the main thread. What happens now? Is the behaviour undefined?

Comment: Very much undefined, yes. There's nothing glibmm-specific about that; it is UB to access an object which has been destroyed.